# PC and LR in same function in Android Kernel

Tags: android, assembly, linux-kernel, arm

I am facing a problem in which the `PC`<sup>1</sup>  and `LR`<sup>2</sup> both are pointing **with in** the function `cpuacct_charge()` in the kernel's sched.c.  Are there any scenario's in which this might happen? My analysis shows no recursion in the `cpuacct_charge()` function.  I cannot provide the code. However, any scenario's when this happens would be a big help.

**For Clarification :** The value of PC and LR points to a different locations in function:
`void cpuacct_charge(struct task_struct *tsk, u64 cputime)`

*Note 1:* `PC` - Program Counter
*Note 2:* `LR` - Link Register

Comment: What do "PC" and "LR" mean?

Comment: @poitroae ARM CPU registers

Comment: Program Counter and Link Register

Comment: How about a memory corruption? If a function calls other functions, it must save `lr` on the stack. And the stack can get corrupted, so when `lr` is restored from it, it can contain garbage.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze If memory got corrupted then how can it be proved, the problem is reproduced

Comment: I'm afraid, not through math, rather through debugging, code reviewing and, perhaps, taking a closer look at the schematics and the device.

Comment: your question is not clear. anyone can modify LR without any side effect, LR is not like PC.

Comment: Are you talking about kernel mode or user mode registers?  Is the task the `init` task or task #1 or do you have other tasks running and scheduling?  How have you deduced information about `PC` and `LR`?  With JTAG, kernel mode GDB, `printk()`?  You have a lot of information besides the source that you haven't provided.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

When a function returns it basically does a branch to the address in the link register.

So, presumably you've paused the program right after a function return.

Comment: The program has not been paused, the value of PC is greater than that of LR and LR does not point to function in which it is there.

The problem has caused a Lock up in the device just after boot up and the problem is getting reproduced

Comment: Paused or not, you've taken the register readings from what they were at a point in time.

Comment: PC *would* be greater than LR after the program has run on a few cycles. I can't parse your statement about LR. The original question suggests both point to the same function.